# Component identification help

Tags: power-supply, identification

I had a component on a monitor internal power supply short out, unfortunately it was quite damaged but I am hoping I can identify it and replace it to repair the screen.

[image: Blown part]

I'm sure you can tell which component is blown in this picture. What are steps I could take to identify the specs so I can order a new one?

Comment: Pretty clear that it is a capacitor. Its value is not that clear. You can try removing it and look for possible markings.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Per your suggestion, I removed the part. It seems to have become quite brittle with the shorting, and the top disintegrated when removing, which I guess is fine since it doesn't have any marking anyways. The bottom also has no markings though. Is there anything I could figure out from the dimensions?

Comment: There is no way you can find out the value other than from the manufacturer documentation (or reverse-engineering the whole circuit and deducing it - but it is not very realistic)

Comment: Generally, that's a larger-sized MLCC cap.  Could be 6.3V rated and 470µF, or 150V rated and 1µF - a wide range.  Power it up with it removed and see what kind of DC/AC will be across it.

Comment: My guess it is used for power supply decoupling, so low-ESR would be the parameter to optimize for.

Comment: It looks like its shunt with an electrolytic on the other side of the board (C122). If you can confirm continuity, you can read the voltage rating on the can of that cap to give yourself a target voltage rating for your replacement without powering the board.

Comment: Now that you've removed the capacitor, is there still a short-circuit across the pads where it was? It is possible that it broke some other component when it shorted - you want to check for that.

Comment: @AndrewMorton there is not a short between the pads, so it seems I am good there.

Comment: @yhyrcanus there is continuity between C103 and C122. The capacitor on the other side says 82µF 100v on it.

Comment: @QuentinSkousen I'd try to match that voltage rating, and get a low (ish) ESR, high (ish) value cap. The capacitance value is likely not very critical, as it'll get washed out by the electrolytic cap. My guess is if you can get a 1-10 uF cap with low ESR, high resonant frequency you'll be good. (eg from a quick digikey search and assuming 1210: C1210X475K101T). If you don't want to take the risk, you can buy that manual/schematic. The other thing is you don't know if the cap is what is actually killing the board, or if it was a casualty. I might get the schematic just in case.

Comment: C128 was soldered by quacks so that could be the source of the problem. I wouldn't trust anything on this board with a botched solder job like this - no serious assembly company skips inspection after a job is done. Looks like it has been through some sloppy wave soldering. And the through-hole component assembly doesn't live up to industry standard either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a capacitor. Generally you would get the service manual for the monitor which has the schematics and part list to figure out which capacitor model and manufacturer it is to find specs for the capacitor C103.

Comment: This is in a Dell U2312HMT, but the only place I can find that says they have a service manual for it wants to charge $10. Is that normal?

Comment: Probably normal, as usually only repair labs are dealing with it. But I could find bunch of forums where you *supposedly* can download the schematics after registration, which I obviously didn't do.

Comment: I bought the service manual, looked up the part, and bought C1812C225K1RACAUTO to replace it. Hopefully it will work!

Comment: Thanks all for your help! I will report back once I have soldered it in.

Comment: Got the part from Digikey today and soldered it in, and the screen works perfectly again!